# Visual studio 2019 preview 2.1 forms designer did not work

Tags: .net-core, windows-forms-designer

I  have Downloaded visual studio 2019 preview 2.1 and created a windows form application but designer mode did not appear.

I have checked the following check box Too

[image: I have checked the following check box Too]

Comment: If you right-click on the Form1.cs file in the Solution Explorer pane, is there an option "View Designer Shift+F7"?

Comment: Yes,I tried to view design by clicking Shift+F7 ,But result was same.